# How to create a granular bash script with multiple variables with ssh connections

Tags: bash, shell, variables, html-table

I have the below script:

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) **Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
###########
printf "\n"
marker=$(printf "%0.s-" {1..60})
printf "|$marker|\n"
printf "|%-10s | %-13s | %-29s |\n" "Hostname" "RedHat Vesrion" "Perl Version"
printf "|$marker|\n"

remote_connect() {
   target_host=$1
   marker=$(printf "%0.s-" {1..60})
   rhelInfo=$(ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no cat /etc/redhat-release| awk 'END{print $7}')
   perlInfo=$(ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no "rpm -qa | grep -i mod_perl")
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
   then
     printf "|%-10s | %-13s | %-20s |\n" "$target_host" "$rhelInfo" "$perlInfo"
   else
     printf "|%-10s | %-13s | %-20s |\n" "$target_host" "Unable to get the ssh connection"
fi
}  2>/dev/null
export -f remote_connect
< /home/zabbix/hostsList.txt  xargs -P30 -n1 -d'\n' bash -c 'remote_connect "$@"' --
```

The above script runs pretty well for me while running in parallel mode.

**Script results:**

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|Hostname   | RedHat Vesrion | Perl Version                  |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|foxnl41    | 6.9           | mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 |
|foxnl84    | 6.9           | mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 |
|foxnl42    | 6.9           | mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 |
|foxnl63    | 6.9           | mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 |
|foxnl10    | 6.7           | mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 |
|foxnl55    | 6.9           | mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 |
|foxnl95    | 6.9           | mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 |
|foxnl85    | 6.9           | mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 |
```

**Concern ?**

I have two variables: `rhelInfo` and `perlInfo` to get store  information.  But it is using two ssh calls to the servers to get the values.

Could I have only one SSH call to execute multiple commands and set both variables?

Comment: Try dsh – distributed shell

Comment: You could do `ssh ... ... -c "command1;command2"` and parse the results in your script.  The output of each command will appear one one line each.  So your result will be on 2 lines.

Comment: @Nic3500, Do you have an example in case i have to run and create multiple variable.

Comment: @ufopilot, sorry i don't have option to choose `dsh`.

Comment: Look at the two answers provided, I cannot offer anything better than this...

Comment: Quick improvement `printf -v marker "%0.s-" {1..60}` instead of `marker=$(printf "%0.s-" {1..60})`

Comment: Why did you tag this with "shell"? Did you read the description of that tag?

Comment: Thanks  Everyone for the nice explanation and help provided, i'll Keep this learning into my wallet for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is how I do *remote data collection* using `ssh`

Some remarks

- As this function is intended to *collect datas*, not to *connect host* (as they don't stay connected), I've renamed them ;-)
- Avoid useless forks! use `printf -v varname ...` instead of `varname=$(printf ...)`
- Moved *`STDERR`* redirection `2>/dev/null` at more suited place.
- use `local` to reserve variables names into function scope.
- `printf` must have correct number of arguments, corresponding to number of `%s` see [This format string has 3 variable...](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2183).
- Don't use `-i` switch to `grep` if not needed!

```bash
remote_collect() {
    local target_host=$1 host_answer rhelInfo perlInfo
    {
        read -r host_answer
        read -r rhelInfo
        read -r perlInfo
    } < <(
        ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" \
            -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no \
            /bin/sh <<-EOF
        hostname
        awk 'END{print $7}' </etc/redhat-release
        rpm -qa | grep mod_perl
EOF
    ) 2>/dev/null
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ;then
        printf "| %-10s | %-14s | %-29s |\n" \
            "host_answer" "$rhelInfo" "$perlInfo"
    else
        printf "| %-10s | %-46s |\n" \
            "target_host" "Unable to get the ssh connection"
    fi
}
```

Notice: the `EOF` mark could be preceded by tabulations <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but **not spaces**! I've dropped tabulation before posting to ensure they won't be converted in space during cut'n paste.

##### And the head line could be

```bash
printf -v marker '%61s' ''
marker=${marker// /-}
printf "+%s+\n| %-10s | %-14s | %-29s |\n+%s+\n" \
   "$marker" "Hostname" "RedHat Version" "Perl Version" "$marker"
```

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hostname   | RedHat Version | Perl Version                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| hostok     | 6.3            | mod_perl-2.0.4-10.el6_5.armf  |
| hostbad    | Unable to get the ssh connection               |
```

##### Pretty table using `UFT-8` borders

```bash
printf -v sl %31s '';sl=${sl// /$'\U2500'}
printf '%b%-12s%b%-16s%b%-31s%b\n' \
    \\U250c "${sl::12}" \\U252c "${sl::16}" \\U252c "$sl" \\U2510 \
    \\U2502 ' Hostname' \\U2502 ' RedHat Version' \\U2502 ' Perl Version' \
    \\U2502   \\U251c "${sl::12}" \\U253c "${sl::16}" \\U253c "$sl" \\U2524
```

then:

```bash
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ;then
        printf "\U2502 %-10s \U2502 %-14s \U2502 %-29s \U2502\n" \
            "$host_answer" "$rhelInfo" "$perlInfo"
    else
        printf "\U2502 %-10s \U2502 %-46s \U2502\n" \
            "$target_host" "      Unable to get the ssh connection"
    fi
```

and finally

```bash
# printf -v sl %31s '';sl=${sl// /$'\U2500'} # uncomment if $sl not at main scope
printf '\U2514%s\U2534%s\U2534%s\U2518\n' "${sl::12}" "${sl::16}" "$sl"
```

should produce:

```
┌────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ Hostname   │ RedHat Version │ Perl Version                  │
├────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┤
│ hostok     │ 6.3            │ mod_perl-2.0.4-10.el6_5.armf  │
│ hostbad    │       Unable to get the ssh connection         │
└────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Why not just `read -r host_answer rhelInfo perlInfo`?

Comment: @Ivan because this comme under 3 different lines. You could `mapfile -t answer < <(..` but once done, you have to parse `${answer[@]}` array...

Comment: @F.Hauri, Thanks for the detailed answer, already +1.

Comment: smart and elegant solution. Good job.

Comment: This is really great way invoking ssh call and nice markers , but i could see deformed printing like below below every hostname ..

`│ inv1146    │       Unable to get the ssh connection         │`

`└┴┴┘`

Comment: @kulfi See last paragraph edied: `$sl` have to be in main scope or re-defined.

Comment: @F.Hauri, Its still the same, does not make any difference its printing `└┴┴┘` below every hostnames, looks like somewhere its interpreting some uniq characters

Comment: @kulfi command `printf -v sl %31s '';sl=${sl// /$'\U2500'};printf '\U2514%s\U2534%s\U2534%s\U2518\n' "${sl::12}" "${sl::16}" "$sl"` output `└────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘` on my host!?

Answer (score 3):

> Could I have only one SSH call to execute multiple commands and set both variables?

Sure. You could do:

```
# this looks too long - so a function
_ssh() {
  ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key \
      -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
      -o PasswordAuthentication=no \
      "root@$target_host" \
      "$@"
}
export -f _ssh

# the function to-be-executed on the remote
remotework() {
    rhelinfo=$(awk 'END{print $7}' /etc/redhat-release)
    perlinfo=$(rpm -qa | grep -i mod_perl)
    # output elements separated by byte 0x01
    printf "%s\001" "$rhelinfo" "$perlinfo"
}
export -f remotework

remote_connect() {
    # execute bash on the remote
    # with `remotework` function serialized
    # and execute the `remotework` function
    # properly `printf %q` quote everything for unquoting done by ssh+remote shell
    tmp=$( _ssh "$(printf "%q " bash -c "$(declare -f remotework); remotework")" )
    # split the output of ssh by byte 0x01
    {
       IFS= read -d $'\x01' -r rhelInfo &&
       IFS= read -d $'\x01' -r perlInfo
    } <<<"$tmp"
}
```

or similar variation of it. Basically `ssh` gives you a bidirection stream of data - you can stream anything with a separator in between ("custom protocol") and then split the data on that separator. I.e. the problem is not limited to ssh - research data serialization/deserialization in bash. Above I have chosen the byte 0x01 to be the separator - you can use a separate line with unique uuid, use `base64 -w0` to convert data to a single line, or similar or use another format.

```
remotework() {
    awk ... | base64 -w0
    echo ' '
    rpm ... | base64 -w0
    echo
}
...
   IFS=' ' read -r rhelInfo perlInfo <<<"$tmp"
   rhelInfo=$(<<<"$rhelInfo" base64 -d)
   perlInfo=$(<<<"$perlInfo" base64 -d)
```

You can also serialize variables with `declare -p` and then `eval` them - this is in my opinion more dangerous, so it's better to use a separator.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuck for the answer , this approach is fantastic, but somehow it does not yields the result. +1

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting to replace following lines:

```
   rhelInfo=$(ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no cat /etc/redhat-release| awk 'END{print $7}')
   perlInfo=$(ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no "rpm -qa | grep -i mod_perl")
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
     printf "|%-10s | %-13s | %-20s |\n" "$target_host" "$rhelInfo" "$perlInfo"
   else
     printf "|%-10s | %-13s | %-20s |\n" "$target_host" "Unable to get the ssh connection"
   fi
```

With following lines:

```
   sshResponseArr=( $(ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no "awk 'END{print}'  /etc/redhat-release; rpm -aq|grep -i mod_perl") ) 
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
     printf "|%-10s | %-13s | %-20s |\n" "$target_host" "${sshResponseArr[6]}" "${sshResponseArr[8]}"
   else
     printf "|%-10s | %-13s | %-20s |\n" "$target_host" "Unable to get the ssh connection"
   fi
```

#### Explanation

First I call multi-line commands in the `ssh` request. Placing all the commands in a single argument with `"` (as you did).

The real trick is to read multi-line `ssh` response into `bash` array variable `sshResponseArr`

By default the array is parsed by   spaces.

I assume (as you did) that words positioning in the array is consistent across all hosts therefore:

`$rhelInfo` is `${sshResponseArr[6]}`

And `$perlInfo` is `${sshResponseArr[8]}`

Alternative conservative handling of `sshResponseArr` as an array of 2 lines response from `ssh` command:

```
 mapfile -t sshResponseLinesArr < <(ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no "awk 'END{print}'  /etc/redhat-release; rpm -aq|grep -i mod_perl")
 lastLineInReleaseFile=${sshResponseLinesArr[0]}
 mod_perl_response=${sshResponseLinesArr[1]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @Dudi Boy, the Array defined doesn't return any output at all. +1

Comment: i noticed there is extra ` ` space mistake in `mod _perm`. Fixed it.

Comment: Suggesting to test `ssh` command `ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no "awk 'END{print}'  /etc/redhat-release; rpm -aq|grep -i mod_perl"` . This command should return 2 lines. If the command returns 2 lines, the `bash` array should be filled.

Comment: How could i test this part `sshResponseArr=( $(ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@inv1568" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no "awk 'END{print}'  /etc/redhat-release; rpm -aq|grep -i mod_perl") )` , while i am doing on the bash shell just to test with `echo ${sshResponseArr}`, is this right?

Comment: printing all member of array `sshResponseArr` : `printf "%s\n" ${sshResponseArr[@]}`

Comment: printing first member `0` of array `sshResponseArr` : `echo "${sshResponseArr[0]}"`

Comment: thnx for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can run both commands in one ssh run and then parse the results, like this for example:

```
...
remote_data=($(
    ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no "
        rhelInfo=\$(cat /etc/redhat-release | awk 'END{print \$7}')
        perlInfo=\$(rpm -qa | grep -i mod_perl)
        
        echo \$rhelInfo \$perlInfo  
"))

rhelInfo=${remote_data[0]}
perlInfo=${remote_data[1]}
...
```

Explanation:
`remote_data=( $(ssh ...) )` - will create an array 'remote_data' and fill it with values from output of the command in `$()` Array will automatically split values by space, tab or new line. So it this case we will have `remote_data=( 6.9 mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 )`

And then these values are assigned to variables:

```
rhelInfo=${remote_data[0]}
perlInfo=${remote_data[1]}
```

BTW echo(and cat)) is an overkill here, so this could be simplified to:

```
...
remote_data=($(
    ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" \
        -o  StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        -o PasswordAuthentication=no "
           awk 'END{print \$7}' /etc/redhat-release
           rpm -qa | grep -i mod_perl
    "
))

rhelInfo=${remote_data[0]}
perlInfo=${remote_data[1]}
...
```

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: Thanks @Ivan for the explanation, already +1.

Answer (score 0):

I am Keeping it here after testing from my side with @F. Hauri answer..

```
#!/bin/bash
###########
printf -v sl %32s '';sl=${sl// /$'\U2500'}
printf '%b%-12s%b%-16s%b%-32s%b\n' \
    \\U250c "${sl::12}" \\U252c "${sl::16}" \\U252c "$sl" \\U2510 \
    \\U2502 ' Hostname' \\U2502 ' RedHat Version' \\U2502 ' Perl Version' \
        \\U2502   \\U251c "${sl::12}" \\U253c "${sl::16}" \\U253c "$sl" \\U2524

remote_collect() {
    target_host=$1
    {
        read -r rhelInfo
        read -r perlInfo
    } < <(
        ssh -i /home/zabbix/.ssh/ssh_key "root@${target_host}" \
            -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no \
            /bin/sh <<-EOF
        cat /etc/redhat-release | awk 'END{print \$7}'
        rpm -qa | grep mod_perl
EOF
    ) 2>/dev/null

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ;then
        printf "\U2502 %-10s \U2502 %-14s \U2502 %-28s \U2502\n" \
            "$target_host" "$rhelInfo" "$perlInfo"
    else
        printf "\U2502 %-10s \U2502 %-14s \U2502  %-29s \U2502\n" \
            "$target_host" "?" "Unable to connect"
    fi
 # printf -v sl %31s '';sl=${sl// /$'\U2500'} # uncomment if $sl not at main scope
 printf '\U2514%s\U2534%s\U2534%s\U2518\n' "${sl::12}" "${sl::16}" "$sl"

} 2>/dev/null
export -f remote_collect
< /home/zabbix/hostsList.txt  xargs -P30 -n1 -d'\n' bash -c 'remote_connect "$@"' --
```

**Output 1:**

```
┌────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ Hostname   │ RedHat Version │ Perl Version                   │
├────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ foxnl46    │ ?              │  Unable to connect             │
└┴┴┘
│ foxnl27    │ 6.7            │ mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 │
└┴┴┘
│ foxnl32    │ 6.7            │ mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 │
```

If i remove the last `printf` it all turns okay expect the last line for table.

**Output 2**

```
┌────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ Hostname   │ RedHat Version │ Perl Version                   │
├────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ foxnl46    │ ?              │  Unable to connect             │
│ foxnl27    │ 6.7            │ mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 │
│ foxnl32    │ 6.7            │ mod_perl-2.0.4-11.el6_5.x86_64 │
```